How do I know if flag was passed by the user or has default value?
Sample code:
import click

@click.command
@click.option('-f/-F', 'var', default=True)
def main(var):
    click.echo(var)

main()


Inside main() function, how can I check if var parameter got True value by default, or it was passed by the user?
What I want to achieve: I will have few flags. When the user does not pass any of the flags, I want them all to be True. When the user passes at least one of the flags, only the passed flags should be True, the other flags False.

Dunno really bout click internals but make default value to be None, check if its None in the first line and set it to True if it was ?

I didn't think it could be this easy, thank you! :). Post this as an answer.

As I haven't really used click - maybe there's some functionality to handle this but as a workaround, I'd set the default value to None and check against if the value if its None when command is called. Something like this:
import click

@click.command
@click.option('-f/-F', 'var', default=None)
def main(var):
    if var is None:
       var = True
       print("No Value Provided - default to True")
    click.echo(var)

main()


Lots of values are false-y (including... False, which seems a likely possibility for a value defaulting to True), using is not None is more idiomatic.

You are correct - addressed
